# Gettint try and catch events after deleting row sql

Tags: sql, jsp, radio-button, delete-row

Hello guys whenever I try to delete a row using a radiobutton, I get both try and catch messages, when it is supposed to be just 1 of them, I have this code

Here's my calling button method

```
    if(request.getParameter("btnEliminar") != null)
    {
                String value;
                int codParse;
                OC_DAO objDAO = new OC_DAO();
                valor = request.getParameter("rbSel");
                codParse = Integer.parseInt(valor);
                objDAO.DeleteRow(codParse);
    }
```

Here's my java code

```
    public void DeleteRow(int codDet)
    {
            try
            {
                cn = Conexion.getConexion();
                pt = cn.prepareStatement("DELETE "
                                       + "FROM detalleProd "
                                       + "WHERE codDet = ?");
                pt.setInt(1, codDet);
                pt.executeUpdate();


            System.out.println("ROW DELETED ON CODDET: " + codDet);
            rs.close();
            pt.close();
            cn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while deleting");
            System.out.println(exc.toString());
        }
    }
```

And here's my log

```
Información:   ROW DELETED ON CODDET: 48
Información:   Error while deleting
Información:   java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is due to `rs.close();`, you have not set value of `rs`,it's null and can not be closed,you just need to remove this line of code.

Your code seems very strange,I do not have see where you declare `rs`,it will compile error in your IDE.

Comment: just removed it! Thanks! It worked, I had it declared like null,